# python loop over a list's length, writing specific data to csv file

Tags: json, python-2.7, csv, python-requests

I am collecting data from a set of urls using curl requests and converting it into json. These data are represented in python as lists or dictionaries.

EDIT: 
Next, I want to loop my script over a value in a dictionary that is inside a list (type list of dictionaries) until the length of the list is met. I wish to loop my other curl requests for each 'instance' and then write that information to a .csv with the name 'instance_name'.csv

Information in the .csv is populated from 2 different curl requests, excluding the one I want to loop everything over. The .csv needs to be created and populated by 'instance_name'. But actual content is populated via other curl requests.

Information of the list I want to loop over:

```
>>> instances = [i['instance_name'] for i in i_data]
>>> print(instances)
[u'Instance0', u'Instance1', .... u'Instance16']
>>> type(i_data)
<type 'list'>
>>> len(i_data)
17
>>> print(i_data[0])
{u'instance_name': u'Instance1', u'attribute2': {u'attribute2_1': u'yes', u'attribute2_2': u'no', u'attribute2_3': u'bye', u'attribute2_4': u'hello', u'attribute2_5': 500}, u'attribute3': u'abcd', u'attribute4': u'wxyz'}
>>>
```

How can I start this loop? eg:

```
i = 0
for i in len(i_data[i]):  
    with open('{}.csv'.format(i['instance_name']), 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
```

Trying to test:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> for i in len(i_data[i]):
...     print('Hello')
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>
```

Secondly, how can I match certain field names in the csv with certain keys from lists or dictionaries?

For a key called 'Id' I want to place the value of that into the .csv file as Id

```
fieldnames = ['Id', 'domain_name', 'website', 'Usage', 'Limit']
```

Should my fieldnames be the same as the Keys so that the values know where to go? Or how exactly can I do this?

I am getting this error right now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./usage_2.py", line 42, in <module>
    writer.writerow(t_data['domain_name'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 152, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: u'p', u'e', u'r', u'f', u'e', u'c', u't', u'u', u's', u'g', u'r', u'e', u'u', u'p', u'a', u'h', u'r', u'.', u'o', u'n', u'm', u'i', u'c', u'r', u'o', u's', u'o', u'f', u't', u'.', u'c', u'o', u'm'
```

Because, I think it's trying to put json data with the u' and also I don't know if data is going where it's suppose to.

One example of to write the data:

```
writer.writerow(t_data['domain_name'])
```

The entry looks like:

```
>>> print(t_data['domain_name'])
abc.123.com
>>>
```

And this 't_data' pulled from another curl request is represented as a dictionary when I check.

```
>>> type(t_data)
<type 'dict'>
>>>
```

Comment: for i in len(i_data[i]): ==> for i in range(len(i_data[i])):

Comment: hey, cool thanks for that tip :)